# Earning the Mortarboard badge Incorrectly

Tags: support, badges

I'm a little confused i just earned the Mortarboard badge when 175 of the reputation came from a bounty when reading the description the maximum is not effected by bounties so why have i just earned this badge?

if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation it says quite clearly

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
>   of the activities below. **Bounty awards, accepted answers, and
>   association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.**

so i should not have earned this badge

Answer (score 7):

The **reputation cap** limits you to earning 200 reputation from upvotes on a single day.

The **Mortarboard badge** has nothing to do with the reputation cap. It is awarded for simply earning at least 200 reputation on that day, whatever it may have come from. They did change the description of the badge, but they left that "(the daily maximum)" thing in there which still confuses users about what applies to the badge.

Comment: `Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.` that reads as you can only earn the daily maximum then going through that link make it say your daily maximum is not affected by bounty reputation i would say that needs changing to just `Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day.`