# `Mortarboard` badge incorrectly given

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I recently asked a (surprisingly) popular [question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274531/zeering-com-profiting-from-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment106560_274531), and I'm a little confused on why I recieved the Mortarboard badge (given when the reputation cap is reached in a single day), since the question was on Meta which doesn't give reputation (and **reputation points don't really exist on Meta**):

[image]

I saw [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267036/earning-the-mortarboard-badge-incorrectly), however it only confirms that it is given when the reputation cap is reached:

> The reputation cap limits you to earning 200 reputation from upvotes
>   on a single day.
>
> The Mortarboard badge has nothing to do with the reputation cap. It is
>   awarded for simply earning at least 200 reputation on that day,
>   whatever it may have come from. They did change the description of the
>   badge, but they left that "(the daily maximum)" thing in there which
>   still confuses users about what applies to the badge.

I learnt that Meta has a 'ghost reputation' that exists, but isn't shown to you; would it be a better idea to update the Meta badge-wiki to include this information?

Comment: I know I've seen this somewhere- But I believe it's a case of, you don't get rep on Meta, but it's still calculated behind the scenes.

Comment: @Kendra I guess it might be used by the system to decide whether to postban a user if they've asked too many low-quality questions. Still, I would've thought Stack Exchange would use the user's actual reputation as seen by everyone to calculate if a user has earned a badge/reputation award/etc.
As it stands, **this is probably a bug and not a [tag:status-bydesign]**.

Comment: On main sites, yes. I [found an answer that mentions this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251251/2607247) but I don't think that's the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Kendra Odd....

Comment: Not odd at all, really. You earn badges on the child metas separate from the main site. Since you don't earn rep here, it's just based on what you _would_ have earned, for badges that are based on rep.

Comment: @Kendra Provided an answer to my own question. It can easily be argued that the Meta tag wiki needs changing slightly to reflect that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Kendra kindly provided the [following Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251249/mortarboard-continues-to-be-awarded/251251#251251) that answers my query, however it could be argued that the Meta tag wiki should be modified to reflect this:

> Badges can be awarded on child metas. And are.
>
> In this case, though there is no associated reputation, the aggregate
>   scores are what's giving these badges out (so, 20 upvotes on answers,
>   for instance, which would on a main site equate to 200 reputation,
>   would award one a mortarboard on the first time that happens).

Probably something along the lines of:

> On Meta, badges are earned by calculating how much reputation you
>   would have if Meta was the main Stack Overflow site.

One other possible idea is to have 'ghost reputation' that is shown to only you on your profile.

Comment: I have the impression it's just 20 upvotes (with questions *perhaps* counting as halves), and accepts *not* counting.